# ArrayCollection instead of Entity

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a function that allows me to retrieve data from a form :

```
public function selectPlayers(Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('joueur', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Joueur::class,         
            'choice_label' => 'prenom',
            'expanded' => 'true',
            'multiple' => 'true'
        ])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $joueurs = $form->getData('joueur');

        return $this->render('disputed/test.html.twig', [
            'joueurs' => $joueurs,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('disputed/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Then, I have a view in which a want to display this data :

```
<h1>Disputed index</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Joueurs</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for joueur in joueurs %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ joueur.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ joueur.nom }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But I get this error message :

> Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "id()",
>   "getid()"/"isid()"/"hasid()" or "__call()" exist and have public
>   access in class "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection".

I understand that I get an ArrayCollection instead of my Entity but I can't see where I can specify that.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where `disputed` variable is created and passed to the view, therefore it's hard to give you any hint.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong view, I'm already doing a loop on the Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake here:

```
$joueurs = $form->getData('joueur');
```

You're doing `getData` on whole form, which fetches whole form's data.

Method `getData` doesn't take any argument, so the `'joueur'` value that you've passed is actually ignored. So it's the same as you would do:

```
$joueurs = $form->getData();
```

I guess that what you've tried to do is:

```
$joueurs = $form->get('joueur')->getData();
```

Comment: Perfect ! Works like a charm ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You send an ArrayCollection to your view.
Try to loop on your view (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong view, I'm already doing a loop on the Array